# Movie with human-sized alien/bugs with guns

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

So all I remember is it having human-sized alien/bugs with guns. The bugs had some sort of, like, antennas in their mouths; they looked like whiskers, but they had just two each. Basically, they were taking over (or had already taken over) the majority of the population. I remember the movie being kinda gruesome, and it had a lot of alien guts. That’s all I really remember. I think it may have been in the sci-fi/horror genre.

Comment: "i think it may have been in the sci-fi/ horror" You mean, you're not sure?

Comment: @jasmin - In roughly which year or decade did you watch this, and when do you think it might've been made?

Comment: Also, if anyone correctly identifies the movie you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Comment: Could it have been a tv show?

Comment: Can you narrow down when you saw it? "Human-sized aliens/bugs with guns" describes a lot of movies.  Did the aliens look like humans in suits, were they computer-generated, animated, ...?

Answer (score 21):

[District 9](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1136608/) has most of the elements described: bugs with two prominent whiskers, guns, gore, body horror.

[image: A 'Prawn']

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/District_9):

> In an alternate 1982, a giant extraterrestrial spaceship arrives at
> Earth and hovers over the South African city of Johannesburg. A human
> investigation team finds over one million malnourished aliens (called
> "Prawns") inside, and the South African government relocates them to a
> terrestrial camp called District 9. However, over the years it turns
> into a slum, and locals from Earth often complain that the aliens are
> filthy, ignorant lawbreakers who bleed resources from humans.

Movie trailer:

Comment: The one thing it's missing is that the aliens weren't trying to take over and were nowhere near being a majority of the population...

Comment: I do realize that, but memories fade and get mixed over time.  I’m often surprised by a correct answer that initially appears to have no relation to the question.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: Many of the scenes are set in the alien slums though, where they *appear* to be a majority of the population; it's apartheid, so the areas are usually mostly alien or mostly human. And there is an implication at the end of the movie that one possible future would be the aliens returning to take revenge on the humans who experimented on them, tortured them, and killed them.

Answer (score 19):

***[Alien Apocalypse](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0404756/)*** (2005)...?

[image: https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/alienfilm/images/c/ce/Alien_%28Alien_Apocalypse%29.jpg/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/640?cb=20180728094819]

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alien_Apocalypse):

> *Alien Apocalypse* is a 2005 Sci Fi channel original movie, directed and written by Josh Becker, and starring Bruce Campbell, Renee O'Connor, Remington Franklin, Michael Cory Davis and Peter Jason. It was released on DVD on March 26, 2005.

From IMDB:

> An astronaut doctor Ivan Hood and his fellow astronaut Kelly return from their mission in space to find the world has been taken over by aliens. Now Dr. Ivan Hood and Kelly must lead a revolution to free the human slaves from their alien masters.

The trailer features human-sized, bug-like aliens with guns, and somewhat antenna-like protrusions from their mouths.

Comment: Anything with Bruce Campbell gets a +1; correct answer or not

Comment: @MivaScott - Yes. Note that Campbell is respected enough in SF cinema circles that he scored the Stan Lee cameo spot in the latest Dr. Strange flick that Lee himself obviously was no longer available for.

Answer (score 10):

Could it have been the tv show [Falling Skies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_Skies)?

The show was post-invasion, had bug aliens called Skitters with two mouth tentacles, gore, guns, etc.

Skitters:

Answer (score 7):

Starship Troopers?!! Most of the bug aliens are the size of us in this, and it was definitely about them trying to eradicate the humans and the humans at war with them, and some gruesome shocks happen in there too. Very gritty, but a bit funny too in a bunch of different ways.
It was made into a movie in 1997.
It was made into an Anime in 1988.
And it was Originally a novel in 1959, written by Robert A. Heinlein.

Good luck in your quest! I know and like two of those other answers up there, so at least there's some good content on your way to tracking it down.

Comment: Masterpiece of a trailer btw. You can see the alien bugs great at about 1:15 of this preview/trailer

Comment: My first guess as well, but the bugs were considerably larger than humans...

Comment: Also, I'm relatively certain the bugs never wielded any mechanical weaponry.

Comment: And the bugs didn't have any intention of "taking over".

Comment: @AlexanderNied I thought that too, but it's been a while since I saw it, and I didn't see all the sequels, so I didn't remember for sure that they *never* used weapons?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman - that's fair :) I feel _relatively_ confident, but it has been quite a long time.  FWIW, [the wikipedia article for Starship Troopers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers_(film)) refers to the bugs as "...a hostile **non-technological** insectoid species..."  That said, I _also_ wouldn't/couldn't rule out that they might wield some weapons in any of the subsequent films.

Comment: Yeah, the bugs in that flick didn't use guns. Some few of them had biological-based ranged weapons, but mostly they relied on melee attacks and wave-assaults.